# Manage liste separator while the screen change size (media query)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-selectors, media-queries

I try to manage separators (like a "-") between each element of a list.
It's relatively simple when we only have one line, but I can't do it with more than one line.

When the site is displayed on a big screen I have:

**Example** *center aligned*

```
Listitem1 - listitem2 - listitem3 - ... - listitemX
```

The last item having no separator "-"

**html**

```
<p>
    <a>listitem1</a>
    <a>listitem2</a>
    <a>listitem3</a>
    <a>listitem4</a>
    <a>listitem5</a>
    <a>listitem6</a>
    <a>listitem7</a>
...
    <a>listitemX</a>
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
a:nth-child(n+2)::before {
  content: " - "
}
```

This is relatively easy in CSS using :: before from the 2nd child...

But with media queries, when my screen shrinks and this same list spans multiple lines, I would like to remove the last "-" separator from each line.

**Example** *center aligned*

```
Listitem1 - listitem2 - listitem3 - listitem4 (without the separator here)
Listitem5 - listitem6 - listitem6 - listitem8 (without separator here either)
Listitem9 - etc ...
```

Does anyone have an idea?
Thank you in advance. Sebastian

Comment: Is the list left/right/center aligned?

Comment: Center aligned!

Comment: To clarify your question, because you’re using `::before` not `::after`, the errant separator would appear at the beginning of each subsequent line (e.g., before Listitem5 and Listitem9), not after items 4 and 8, right?

Comment: yes and no ... because it is the browser that manages the line breaks, considering everything as text.


if you use ```<ul> <li>``` tags you would be absolutely right

Comment: @Noleli it seems that the browser might separate out the before (and I assume therefore an after if there was one) from its li - this makes even a JS solution rather difficult as we cannot assume that the pseudo element and its element are on the same line,

Comment: this is the kind of response I feared.

Comment: @A Haworth
I did not understand the purpose of the first question, but indeed on the right or on the left ... We can hide Xpx from the parent

Comment: You can force them to stay on the same line by setting `white-space: nowrap`. You also need to set `display: inline-block` so `getClientRects()` works right. I _almost_ have it working at [this codepen](https://codepen.io/noleli/pen/abpGjOZ), but it’s finicky because removing the “ - ” makes it take less space, so wrapping gets wonky.

Comment: it is already not bad and quite short. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn’t seem to be a pure CSS solution, but you can use a bit of JS to set or unset a class based on whether an item is the first in a line.

Here I’m setting the text color to transparent rather than the content to "" because changing the content affects width, which then jumps around as it wraps/resizes.

```css
a.firstInLine::before {
    color: transparent;
}
```

The Javascript goes through the nodes and checks whether it’s lower on the page than the previous node. If it is (by more than a small margin of error), it sets the class `firstInLine`:

```js
function calcY() {
    document.querySelectorAll("p a").forEach((n, i, nodes) => {
        if(i > 0) {
            const thisY = n.getClientRects()[0].y;
            const prevY = nodes[i - 1].getClientRects()[0].y;
            
            if(thisY - prevY > 4) {
                n.classList.add("firstInLine");
            }
            else {
                n.classList.remove("firstInLine");
            }
        }
    });
}

window.addEventListener("resize", calcY);
calcY();
```

I should add that there are a couple of other CSS things to set. We don’t want it to wrap, and in order for `getClientRects` to work right, it can’t be a purely inline element, so:

```css
a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/noleli/pen/abpGjOZ)

Comment: Thank you, the centering is still not perfect, lol thank you very much nice solution ;-)

Comment: Yeah, turning the separator transparent means the centering will be a bit off. You might be able to resolve it by playing with some margins.

Comment: you are right:
```

a.firstInLine::before {
    color: transparent;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```
Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it worked! If you don’t mind, mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: I am Belgian and speak French, this is my first question on this site even if I have known the site for a long time.
I have been looking for where to confirm your answer for 5 minutes lol ...

Where is this button ?

Got it.